# How to show the HOVER attribute on IE11

Tags: html, css

I am setting a `:hover` attribute on a table to change the row color on hover. It is working fine on CHROME and EDGE but not on IE 11.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd'>
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=9; IE=10; IE=11;IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE'/>
```

CSS part:

```
tr.fullrow:hover{
    background:yellow;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

HTML part:

```
<table border = "1" class ="tablewip">
    <caption> Assy WIP by Product </caption>
      <thead>
         <tr class ="headerrow">
         <td class="headercells" font-size:100px;  nowrap >'.$colHeader.'</td>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr class = "fullrow">
            <td  class = "wipcells" nowrap >Text </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Stack snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd'>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=9; IE=10; IE=11;IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE' />
  <style>
    tr.fullrow:hover {
      background: yellow;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1" class="tablewip">
    <caption> Assy WIP by Product </caption>
    <thead>
      <tr class="headerrow">
        <td class="headercells" font-size:100px; nowrap>'.$colHeader.'</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="fullrow">
        <td class="wipcells" nowrap>Text </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The hover works perfectly fine. However, your markup is invalid. Note inline style should go inside a `style` attribute and `nowrap` should be `white-space: nowrap;`.

Answer (score -2):

For the CSS part try the following:

```
tr.fullrow:hover{
    background-color:yellow;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

See this example: https://codepen.io/pjamourik/pen/EGBgEy

Comment: As the `background:yellow;`, the short hand version, works as good as the long hand `background-color:yellow;`, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The shorthand version is used to specify all the background properties in a single property; If you need to specify only the color property then use background-color.

Comment: As the shorthand version can target one or many background properties in one line (and is often used to do so, to make sure to overwrite any previous settings), your answer doesn't solve the question asked.

Answer (score -2):

I would style **td** of hovered element instead of **tr**. For example:

```
tr.fullrow:hover td{
    background:yellow;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

Comment: OP asks how to style the `tr`, not what to style instead, which by the way could be any descendant of a `tr`, hence making this answer irrelevant as it does not answer the question asked.